# How can I access an Amazon RDS with key-pair?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon RDS. I am able to access Amazon RDS via vpc from a static ip. To access from a non-static ip what are my options ?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are one of the two following:

1. Update your security group each time the IP changes. (May be able to script something using the command line tools)
2. Create a VPN or SSH tunnel through another instance. Give that instance access to RDS.